# F# filetypes icons missing

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017, registry, explorer

So after updating visual studio 2017 to the 15.8.8 version the `.fs` `.fsi` and `.fsx` filetypes have no icon on windows explorer.

I have checked the following registry keys to see if they were there, but no...they aren't.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`

and

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`

I found an issue in GitHub

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/4017

So I could find for other filetypes like `.cs` or `.cpp` there is a registry key 
like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.css.aaa3ca14\DefaultIcon` with the value of the dll where the icon is taken from

Could someone please provide me with the keys and values for the extensions 
`.fs` `.fsi` and `.fsx` ?

I uninstalled, cleaned up the registry and installed again the visual studio 2017 and the problem is still there.

**Win 10 [Versión 10.0.17763.55]**

**Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.8.8**

**F# 4.5**

*edit:*

found two issues more:

https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3351

https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3352

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I found a workaround by exporting the reg keys from a working machine where VS2015 was installed.

I created a repository in case someone has the same problem until they fix the issue.
https://github.com/blfuentes/Fsharp_File_extensions